# Generating a string based on vector data

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say that i have an unknown size  array like 0,1,2,3...

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
  string name;
  int number;

  if (array[i] == 0)
  {
    name ="jack";
    number="10";
  }
  else if (array[i] == 1)
  {
    name="alice";
    number=15"; 
  }
  //....
}
```

Using this data I would like to generate a string like:

```
string text = name(number)+name(number)+name(number)...
```

There must be  array.size() times name(number) in string

How do I do write code for this?

Comment: Look at `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Just initialize an empty string before your loop and append your name and your number in every iteration. You can just write text += name + "(" + to_string(number) +")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> array;
    array.push_back(std::make_pair("jack", 10)); //index 0
    array.push_back(std::make_pair("alice", 15)); //index 1
    array.push_back(std::make_pair("bob", 20)); //index 2

    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (auto &el : array)
    {
        oss << el.first << "(" << el.second << ")";
    }

    std::string text = oss.str();
    std::cout << text;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
jack(10)alice(15)bob(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream out_stream;
out_stream << name << "(" << "number" << ")";
//...
std::cout << out_stream.str() << std::endl;
```